# Error in Virtual Folder Type creating Bundle in PowerShell

Tags: 2013-sp1, bundles, powershell

I've *finally* worked through a number of syntactical challenges translating the Core Service API into PowerShell instructions for the seemingly simple task of creating a Bundle via PowerShell.

Using the code below I get the error shown:

```
$bundleFolderData = new-object VirtualFolderData
$location="tcm:aa-bb-2";
$bundle = $core.GetDefaultData([ItemType]::VirtualFolder, $location, $defaultReadOptions);
$bundle.Configuration = "<Bundle xmlns=""http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/Bundle""><Items /></Bundle>"
$bundle.TypeSchema = new-object LinkToSchemaData
$bundle.TypeSchema.IdRef = "tcm:aa-cc-8"
$core.Create($bundle, $defaultReadOptions)
```

> Exception calling "Create" with "2" argument(s): "Unknown Virtual
>   Folder Type:
>   "http://aaa.net/tridion/schemas/workflow/content-escalation". A 
>   Virtual Folder Cartridge is not registered for this type." At line:1
>   char:1
>   + $core.Create($bundle, $defaultReadOptions)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FaultException`1

I've checked that the schema reference is the one I want to add to the Bundle and that it exists.

I've tried mixing and matching the Publication references form owning to contextual to no avail... an pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FOUND IT.

Eventually I realised that it wasn't the schema I wanted to attribute to the Bundle - but the schema I want to base the Bundle on (hence the **Virtual Folder** Reference!)

Adding the following script did just the job (note that this method is better than simply getting the ID and plugging it in for transportability of the scripts in other environments *and yes, I see I've used ID's in the example code above ;)*  )

```
$bundleNameSpace = "http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/Bundle"
[SchemaData]$schema = $core.GetVirtualFolderTypeSchema($bundleNameSpace);
$bundleSchemaId = $schema.Id
$bundle.TypeSchema.IdRef = $bundleSchemaId
$core.Create($bundle, $defaultReadOptions)
```

Boom!

Comment: See the follow-up question here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13885/error-in-bundle-workflow-schema-addition-in-powershell